# How to detect click event on a 3rd party control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click

I have a 3rd party video control placed inside a WinForms UserControl.  I want to handle click events on the video control.  The problem is the 3rd party control doesn't expose Click event.  Initially I was going to place a transparent label on top of the 3rd party control, and handle its Click event instead.  It worked, but the problem is WinForm Labels don't support transparency when placed on top of video.

Any ideas for workarounds?

Here's the list of events that the 3rd party video control exposes:

```
MouseCaptureChanged
Enter
Leave
Validated
Validating
PreviewKeyDown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use hooks,

here is a good starting point

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804